# Glassfish JMX interface

Tags: glassfish-3, jmx

I can connect glassfish 3.1 JMX interface via jconsole. 
I would like to know how I can check the uptime of each instance in a specified cluster.
I can learn their status and ip with the following objectname and operation pair via JMX

amx:pp=/domain/servers,type=server,name=instanceMaster->isRunning()
amx:pp=/domain/servers,type=server,name=instanceMaster->getAdminHost()

This uptime value of each instance can be captured via restfull interface.
http://47.168.96.31:4848/management/domain/clusters/cluster/cluster1/list-instances

Thanks ins advance

Answer (score 1):

Mmc18 the reason you can not connect to the node of the cluster with JMX is because there is a bug in 3.1.2 that prevents remote access to instances via JMX. http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18450 this bug has been fixed but only in glassfish 4, however, there is someone on there that ported the fix to 3.1.2

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try to connect via JMX in glassfish 4.0

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the uptime of a JVM by interrogating the [RuntimeMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html). It exposes an attribute called [Uptime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getUptime%28%29) which is the number of milliseconds since the JVM started. The ObjectName of the RuntimeMXBean is the constant [java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.RUNTIME_MXBEAN_NAME.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#RUNTIME_MXBEAN_NAME)

Comment: thanks for your answer Nicholas, but for this way there needs to be establish another connection in addition to established JMX ones. Besides pid should be known for this approach, which makes system fragile.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question.  Can you not request the uptime from the existing jmx connection?

Comment: I could not request the uptime of an instance via JMX request. Actually I could not find the ObjectName for this aim. As I said in the question i can reach it via restfull interface. Interesing point is that as far as I know restful interface uses jmx. So I am able to reach this value somehow via jmx.